# Resample daily data into weekday data

Tags: python, pandas

i´m a beginner but i can´t seem to find a way with resample in pandas to turn daily ohlc data into separate weekdays to analyze weekday return over a period of time and how it changed.(turn it into weekly data for exmaple tuesdays as a "weekstart" and just using first so i don´t see the data for the remaining days)

Hope this question is not too stupid but i´m trying to figure it out since a few days but i haven´t found a working solution.

Thanks in advance !

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("ethusdt.csv",parse_dates=["time"], index_col="time")

ohlc_dict = {
    'open':'first',
    'high':'max',
    'low':'min',
    'close':'last',
    'volume':'sum',
    'daily_change':'sum'
    }
df = df.resample('W').agg(ohlc_dict)

weeklydf = df.resample('W').agg(ohlc_dict)
weeklydf['weekly_change'] = ((weeklydf['close'] / (weeklydf['open'])-1)*100)
```

EDIT:

Since i probalby haven´t explained my tought correctly( my english is not very good, sorry) i´ll try to explain the Problem again,

in the Dataframe i have following Data: Open, high, low, close, and volume. My goal is it to resample it to weekly data what i already got but with different starting days, for example with the data right now the daily start is always monday , but i wan´t to change it to all the different weekdays to find changes how the cryptocurrency market "frontruns" itself slowly. Have seen this for a long time but would like to have statistical proof

Comment: Please provide the input data, ideally as a minimal example

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i updated the post. Hopefully it is more understandable now.

Comment: use ```df.to_dict()``` and paste the result in your question. This way you'll provide us with some data to find a solution to your question.